# loop functions in scheme

Tags: list, loops, scheme, racket

Question about loops.

Doing this with lists always confuses me. How would you do something like this?

```
(define-struct song (title artist length))

(define song1 (make-song "Hey, Jude" "The Beatles" 431))
(define songs (list song
    (make-song "Sing" "JB" 200)
    (make-song "Yell" "LS" 188)))

(check-expect (count songs) 819)
```

counts the length of all songs

```
(define (count n)
  (cond
    [(empty? n) 0]
    [else
   (first n)
(count (rest n)))
```

How would you go with this? With structures you could simply break them apart. `(+ (song-length)...` Not sure how to go on about this in lists though.  For instance, I am not sure what is `first` and `rest` in `songs1` or `songs`

Comment: There's a typo in this line: `(define songs (list song`. I believe it should be `(define songs (list song1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is easy, so I won't spoil the fun. In fact, you almost got it! Use this template:

```
(define (count n)
  (cond
    [(empty? n) 0]
    [else
     (+ <???>
        (count (rest n)))]))
```

What's missing? just ask the current song (the *first* song) in the list, what's its length. The recursion will take care of adding them all.

It's the same template you'd use for iterating over any other list:

- Ask if the list is empty and return a value appropriate for this case. Because we're *adding* numbers, returning `0` is fine, it will end nicely the recursion
- If the list is non-empty, simply take the value of interest from the first element (the song's length in this case), *combine* it with the recursive call (with `+`, again because we're *adding* numbers) and advance the recursion to process the rest of the list

Comment: Ok. I am getting 431 for the first case, but I get an error though saying it  expects a non-empty list. I am doing (first (song-length n)). Isn't that a list?

Comment: @Josh that's not right. `n` is a _list_, you have to get its first element, which is a _song_, and then ask for the _length_ of that song. As it is currently, your code is asking for the `song-length` of a list, and clearly that's going to fail

Comment: Jesus Christ. I got it to work. Cant believe this took me so long. Thanks

Comment: @Josh great! glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Each element of a list of songs is a song.  Given such a list `songs`, `(car songs)` is the first element of the list.  `(song-length (car songs))` returns the length of the first song in the list.  It looks like you're trying to sum the length of all the songs.   Idiomatically, it'd probably look more or less like this:

```
(define (sum-lengths songs)
  (let sl ((songs songs)
           (sum 0))
    (if (null? songs) sum
      (sl (cdr songs) (+ sum (song-length (car songs)))))))
```

This pattern is really just computing a `fold`.  You could also write

```
(defun (sum-lengths songs)
  (foldl 0 (lambda (song sum) (+ sum (song-length song))) songs))
```

Personally, I think it's a bit clumsy that you have to write that `lambda` function just to apply `song-length` to each of the songs.  You could also do

```
(foldl 0 + (map song-length songs))
```

but that will build an intermediate list to hold the song lengths.  I prefer Common Lisp's `reduce`, wherein you can specify a `key` function that gets applied to each element of list, with which you could write:

```
(reduce '+ songs :key 'song-length)
```